# How to solve overfitting when you have sufficient data

Tags: python

Notebook Implementation: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MoSnUlnUyWo5A15gEuFPEwNCfFl62YcW?usp=sharing

So I've been debugging a CNN model on classifying people based on ECG and I just keep getting really high accuracy from first epoch.

> Background

The data is sourced from [Physionet MIT-BIH](https://www.physionet.org/content/mitdb/1.0.0/), I only extracted normal beats for each individual, particularly control classes. I have segmented and converted the signals into images.

I experimented with both types of image inputs:

Normal representation VS [Time series recurrent representation](https://www.kaggle.com/tigurius/recuplots-and-cnns-for-time-series-classification)

[image] [image]

I have 5 classes, each with -+2800 samples (definitely sufficient), meaning 13806 total samples. Also no class imbalance. No need for augmentation because the signals are already long and all beats really slightly appear different.

[image]

> Training

```
Training (9664, 256, 256, 3)
Validation (3727, 256, 256, 3)
Test (415, 256, 256, 3)
```

[image]

My data is shuffled, in `np.array()` format, and normalized to `0-1`. I'm using a `LabelBinarizer()` for classes.

> Network

```
def block(model, fs, c):
  for _ in range(c):
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=fs, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))

  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.25))
  return model

# Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation='relu', input_shape=IMAGE_DIMS))

model = block(model, 64, 1)
model = block(model, 128, 2)
model = block(model, 256, 3)

# Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# softmax classifier
model.add(Dense(len(lb.classes_), activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

STEPS_PER_EPOCH = len(x_train) // BS
VAL_STEPS_PER_EPOCH = len(x_valid) // BS

# train the network
H = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=BS,
              validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid),
              steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
              validation_steps=VAL_STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
              epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)
```

> History

Just for 10 epochs??

[image]

Comment: I can't see the overfitting part. Your training and validation loss are quite close to each other. If that's an unexpected result from your view, I suggest you checking data.

Comment: Well, my concern arose because the training accuracy was already high in the first epoch. Isn't the pattern showing memorizing instead of actually learning?

Comment: If your model was memorizing, then validation accuracy would be poor as well as validation loss.